# Custom renderer for Grid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, renderer

I am trying to create a custom `Renderer` in `UWP` for `Xamarin.Forms.Grid`, but I can't figure out the type-parameters for `ViewRenderer<TElement, TNativeElement>` can anybody help me?

I tried with `ViewRenderer<Grid, FrameworkElement>` but `Control` is `null`

Comment: Did you try to use native `Grid`: `ViewRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.Grid, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid>`. I could have mistake in namespaces.

Comment: Yes, and `Control` is `null` :(

Comment: You can try something like this.. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44720/what-is-the-nativeelement-for-windows-phone-for-viewrenderer-for-a-view

Comment: `System.Windows.FrameworkElement` does not exist

Comment: I created renderer `ViewRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.View, Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement>`, but got `null` in `Control`, too. Maybe, I missed some sdk on my pc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the Control by overriding OnElementChanged
So Implement your view renderer by inheriting like you did above:

```
ViewRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.Grid, XControl.Grid>
```

then override OnElementChanged:

```
using XControl = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
.
.
.
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<XControl.Grid> e)
{
   if (e.NewElement != null)
   {
      if (Control == null)
      {
         var container = new XControl.Grid();
         SetNativeControl( container);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure when overriding OnElementChanged to call the base.OnElementChanged before check if control is null otherwise it will be null

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
           Control.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.Red;

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

For my purposes I used:

```
ViewRenderer<Grid, Android.Widget.GridView>
```